Automated Wake-Up and Flight Control for DJI Mini 4 Pro via ESP32
I'm looking for a solution on how to wake up the DJI Mini 4 Pro with a signal sent from the ESP32 to the DJI control module or from ESP32 directly yo the drone.
Here is what I want to achieve:

The DJI Mini 4 Pro is 'sleeping.'
It is woken up by a signal from the ESP32 , sent directly to the drone (via WiFi) or through the DJI control module.
It takes off and flies along a preset route for 3-4 minutes; the same time it is transmitting video to a streaming service.
It lands at the place from where it took off.
It 'sleeps' until the next 'wake up' call.

Well, I was searching for an SDK or a manual on how to program the DJI Mini 4 Pro, but I have failed to find any meaningful information.

You cannot communicate directly with a DJI Drone - It uses a proprietary connection to the controller, which can then be connected to a device running an app built on one of the DJI Developer SDKs. You would have to build that app and have your ESP communicate with it somehow - I'd personally recommend the Mobile SDK as it's the most complete feature-wise, although it's still incredibly frustrating to use due to sparse documentation.
